# Expected value in graph

Tags: graph-theory, expectation

You are in a directed weighted graph with $N$ $(63 \le N \le 10^6)$ vertices and $M$ $(1 \le N \le 10^6)$ edges and you want to get from $63^{rd}$ to $4^{th}$ vertex. Going through $i^{th}$ edge takes you $t_i$ hours $(1 \le t_i \le 24)$. A big monster wants to kill you. He appears in the $i^{th}$ edge $f_i$ times per 24 hours randomly. What is the lowest expected value of you meeting with monster?

Input: In the first line we've got $N$ and $M$. In the $M$ following lines there are descriptions of the edges. In each line there is 4 numbers - $a_i, b_i, t_i, f_i$. It means that $i^{th}$ edge is directed from $a_i$ to $b_i$.

Output: You should give one number. The lowest possible expected value of you meeting with monster.

Example:

Input:

```
64 3
63 4 24 24
63 2 5 1
2 4 5 1
```

Output:

```
0.416667
```

Comment: Just to clarify, on your first edge specified as `63 4 24 24`, since this edge takes $24$ hours to traverse and the monster is there "*$24$ times per $24$ hours randomly*" (so he is there all the time?) there is a $100\%$ change of meeting the monster on that edge? Is $f_i$ the number of hours that the monster is on an edge per $24$ hours?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you could use some adaptation of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) with a [min-priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue) where the weight of each edge is the probability of meeting the monster on that edge.